# How to spy on a method in Java with Junit?

Tags: java, testing, junit, jasmine, mocking

I like Jasmine, because you can check if a function was called, and what was passed to it.

Is there a way do this with junit and java?

Basically, I have function that calls a log function.  I want to assure that function is being call, and is being called with the correct values.

Note, we only have one production build, there is not a test build and production, so mocking make be an issue.

GC_

Answer (score 1):

You want to look into Mockito. You can use it in your unit tests to mock a service and then also spy on it. Below is a Kotlin pseudo code.

```
@Mock
private val myService : MyService? = null

@InjectMocks
private val myController: MyController? = null

myController?.controllerStuff(param1)
Mockito.verify(myService, Mockito.times(1))?.doSomething(param2)
```

Comment: For that, don't you need to make a test build?  You can't run the junit test on production code, correct?

Comment: Usually in Java, you let a build tool such as Gradle or Maven build your project. Such a build tool, will (among other things) build production binaries, build test binaries, launch tests, and then package production binaries